# Concurrency issue while inserting and updating array elements using MongoDb Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have an embedded array of messages with the following schema

```
{ 
"_id" : NumberInt(5), 
"CurrentOwnerId" : NumberInt(9), 
"LastSent" : ISODate("2019-06-21T11:57:32.861+0000"), 
"Messages" : [
    {
        "_id" : BinData(3, "nuC1iYTKtkGzSuv7pVHsKg=="), 
        "MessageContent" : "Hi There", 
        "Status" : "Pending", 
        "DateSent" : ISODate("2019-06-21T11:57:32.861+0000"), 
        "Method" : "Slack",
        "TimeStamp" : "Its Time to party!"
    }
 ]
}
```

I have a requirement that upon insert that I check the previous message in the array and remove the time stamp and append a new one to new message(for the frontend) . Like Below

```
{ 
"_id" : NumberInt(5), 
"CurrentOwnerId" : NumberInt(9), 
"LastSent" : ISODate("2019-06-21T11:57:32.861+0000"), 
"Messages" : [
    {
        "_id" : BinData(3, "nuC1iYTKtkGzSuv7pVHsKg=="), 
        "MessageContent" : "Hi There", 
        "Status" : "Pending", 
        "DateSent" : ISODate("2019-06-21T11:57:32.861+0000"), 
        "Method" : "Slack",
        "TimeStamp" : "" // Gone 
    }
      {
        "_id" : BinData(3, "nuC1iYTKtkGzSuv7pVHsKg=="), 
        "MessageContent" : "Hello Back", 
        "Status" : "Pending", 
        "DateSent" : ISODate("2019-06-21T11:58:32.861+0000"), 
        "Method" : "Slack",
        "TimeStamp" : "Its the new Time to party!" // New one 
    }
 ]
}
```

This is what my code looks like for now

```
       var message = Message.CreateToContactMessage(messageType, content);
       var latestMessage = await _conversationRepository.FindLatestMessageByContactIdAsync(contactId);

        Message.DiscernTimeStampByRef(message, latestMessage);
        if (latestMessage == null)
        {
            //This means its the first message
            await _conversationRepository.InsertMessageAsync(contactId, message);
        }
        else
        {
            await _conversationRepository.UpdateMessage(contactId, latestMessage);
            await _conversationRepository.InsertMessageAsync(contactId, message);
        }
```

This works all fine and well while debugging but under load we start seeing concurrency issues such as time stamps not correctly set due to race conditions between the update and insert.

I have tried a mirage of things from pulling , pushing in the same query ( mongo doesn't like that ) or adding and then deleting, using session and transactions but none have been able to help, I have tried looking into upserting into arrays but this is apparently not possible.

Currently I don't see a way around this without redesigning my schema and putting my messages in  a separate collection where I can then upsert.

I somehow need to do this sequentially to ensure that the correct order is maintained.

Any examples or reading material would be appreciated.

Comment: The only way I can think of is to rewrite the whole array in an update. I don't think you can do this atomically with a combination of array operations. Since you're having so much trouble with this, isn't it better in the long term to put the array in a separate collection? It will make this operation very simple and fast.

Comment: @kevinadi Im worried about bringing the entire document into memory once the array gets quite big. Im not sure what the performance impact would be. If I had to move the messages into a separate collection what would be your advice to associate messages to my conversation ? By reference ie bson id?

Comment: Why wouldn't you combine the 2 updates into a single query?

Comment: @Skami mongodb does not allow multiple operations on a nested array.

Comment: @cl0ud, Ah yes good point. I'll think about it once I've had some coffee.

Comment: @Skami - Just finished my first cup and re approaching this problem, will keep an eye out (: